# Using SOAP in java

Tags: java, soap

I used SOAPUI to call a web service and generate the axis2 java code. My question is how would I go about compiling and running this application as I get error after error when I try to compile it. There are so many external libraries that I am having to add manually. How would I go about getting my program running.

Comment: Discerning the meaning of the error messages, or at least providing them here for reference so that we may, would be a better start.

Comment: Its just that in eclipse it doesnt even compile. Cannot instantiate the type ADBDataSource although i have added the jar.

Comment: no stack trace or anything? Just that one little message?

Comment: Resolve each error one by one until you have no more errors.

Answer (score 0):

What error messages are you getting when you are compiling it? Need a lot more info to work it out, i was havign problems with SOAP using JAX-WS and it turned out to be the network configuration.
Are you running locally or remotely?
-ben